# Why does abnormal mitosis takes place in the cells of tapetum?

Tags: plant-physiology, mitosis, flowers

I know that the tapetal cells present in the anther are binucleate. I also know this means that after karyokinesis the cell does not divide itself and instead form a syncytium.  This occurs due  to abnormal mitosis, but I don't find a reason for abnormal mitosis to occur.

What is the reason for abnormal mitosis to occur?